# How do i show images of all installed apps in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, animation

How do i show images of all installed apps in a recyclerView in android with an animation like it is being scanned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get access the necessary data.

```
val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
val appsList: List<ResolveInfo> = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0)
```

after getting the list of apps, use can use this library https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators to animate the list if it is what you asked for.

Comment: you can use the above code in activity or fragment then pass data to recyclerview.